# Where I do find a 12v accessory power in a 2008 Pontiac G5?

Tags: electrical, pontiac, wiring, cruise-control, g5

I'm trying to install a cruise control in my 2008 Pontiac G5. It's made by Rostra. It needs 12v accessory power. I think I need to go to the fuse box, but does anyone have any idea which wire to tap into?

Second question: one wire is supposed to tap into "Accessory 12 Volt" power, and another wire is supposed to tap into "Accessory Power Source". Aren't these the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Is accessory power source some kind of bad translation for always hot or battery voltage?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the wiring diagram that gives you the codes, then you can start by either:

1) identifying the fuses and what they supply can give an easy and quick idea of permanent supply, accessory supply and ignition controlled supply.

2) use a multimeter to find wires with the controlled supply needed. Make sure that the wires come from a supply point that can supply sufficient current - which depends on how much does the cruise control needs.

As for the question 2, there must be some more explanation somewhere.